# Representing number domain by a symbol

Tags: equation-solving, assumptions

I'd like to represent the number domain by a symbol rather than text word.

While

```
Solve[n^2 - 19 n + 99 == k^2 \[And] {k, n} > 0, {k, n}, Integers]
```

works fine, I'd like to replace `Integers` with $\mathbb{Z}$ (ESC dsZ ESC) and of course for other domains such as `Reals`, `Rationals`, and so on.

But that doesn't work:

[image]

Comment: You can use `esc ints esc` instead.

Comment: @CarlWolf:  AHHH... THAT is it!  Thanks so much.  Your answer actually gives a slightly different symbol (a bit larger) than ESC dsZ ESC.  If you post this as a solution, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Per the [documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Integers#1930604077) you can use <kbd>Esc</kbd> <kbd>i</kbd><kbd>n</kbd><kbd>t</kbd><kbd>s</kbd> <kbd>Esc</kbd> to enter the [`StandardForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StandardForm) symbol for [`Integers`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Integers)